# Loading, sorting, and parsing a large csv file in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm using the following code to read, sort, and remove duplicates from a large file and it works fine as a 1d array.
What I need to do is load a 2d CSV file, sort and remove duplicates based on the PLU number but then delete records based on the status field.
How do I load a 2d CSV file into a .net array and how do I sort it and remove duplicates based on the PLU number.

PLU,Status
000000002017,001100000000
000000002020,001108000000
000000004469,004108000000
000000009361,000A88001000
000000030001,000108000000
000000030002,010008000000
000000007306,000100000000
000000009361,000A88001000
000000030001,000108000000
000000030002,010008000000

```
$ItemArray = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($S4Report)
[Array]::Sort($ItemArray)
$CleanArray = [linq.enumerable]::Distinct($ItemArray) #Writes the new array without any dulicates.


if (Test-Path $S4Report) { Remove-Item $S4Report }

try
{
    $ItemList = [system.IO.StreamWriter]::new($S4Report)
    $CleanArray | ForEach-Object
    {
        Write-Output $_(0)
        $ItemList.WriteLine($_)
    }
}
finally
{
    $ItemList.close()
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `1d` and `2d` array? a CSV file is ALWAYS a collection of rows [a 1d array] ... and that makes a single dimension array when imported into PoSh.

Comment: Goodness knows I may be confused but my impression was that because I have more than one piece of information (in this case PLU and Status) per row that made it 2 dimensional.

Comment: nope ... that just means there is more than one _property_ per object. [*grin*] importing a CSV gives you one object per row, and one property for that object per column.